# How to setup urlpatterns for ASGI Django Channels http type protocol?

Tags: python, django, django-channels, asgi

I am pretty sure I am missing something from the documentation,
but I am unable to find a definitive answer anywhere.

I have a Django application, and what I'd like to do is use Django Channels for websocket purposes, however I am also interested in async http that Django Channels can provide for me.

Looking all over the internet and also in the source code of Django Channels,
the only kinds of examples I was able to find match the ones from the [documentation](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/routing.html)

where "http" property in ProtocolTypeRouter is set to `get_asgi_application`,
and only websockets have their own urlpatterns.

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # Django's ASGI application to handle traditional HTTP requests
    "http": django_asgi_app,

    # WebSocket chat handler
    "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter([
                path("chat/admin/", AdminChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
                path("chat/", PublicChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
            ])
        )
    ),
})
```

I can't understand how to set up urlpatterns that http property will route to.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work, use below syntax,first use webscocket if you are not using( like i removed to understand better)

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # Django's ASGI application to handle traditional HTTP requests
    "http": django_asgi_app,
    'channel': ChannelNameRouter({
            'channel-name': ConsumerName.as_asgi(),
        })
})
```